# Java - reading international characters

Tags: java, internationalization

If I save an international character like in Japanese, which takes more than 1 byte to represent, in UTF-8 will I lose data while I read it back?

I mean, if I use UTF-8, I would use 2 bytes to save one character. And while I am reading the bytes, I may read the first byte before reading the second byte and in that case it would show an entirely different character or gibberish?

Is there a way to save these international characters and read them without using any encoding and decoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I save an international character like in Japanese, which takes more than 1 byte to represent, in UTF-8 will I lose data while I read it back?

No.  You won't lose data if you write / read the file correctly.

And the simple way to write / read text correctly is to use the `Writer` and `Reader` APIs either explicitly specify the encoding when you construct the writer / reader instances (e.g. using InputStreamReader / OutputStreamWriter), or use FileReader / FileWriter and rely on the default platform encoding.  The Java implementation takes care of the char <--> byte encoding and decoding for you, based on the encoding scheme that is explicitly or implicitly selected.

> I mean, if I use UTF-8, I would use 2 bytes to save one character.

Actually, one, two or three bytes depending on the Java `char` value.

> And while I am reading the bytes, I may read the first byte before reading the second byte and in that case it would show an entirely different character or gibberish?

If you don't decode the UTF-8 correctly (i.e. according to the spec) you could get all sorts of garbage.  But you shouldn't be trying to decode it by hand anyway.  Use the Reader and Writer APIs and Java will take care of all of that stuff for you.

> Is there a way to save these international characters and read them without using any encoding and decoding?

This doesn't make sense.  Whenever you write characters from Java to a file you are *implicitly* encoding them ... even if the encoding is an identity transformation (e.g. UTF-16)

Comment: @Stephen...The FileReader and FileWriter constructor does not take any encoding.

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 is exactly what you need. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8.